# Programmatically hiding many files when creating hybrid iso with hdiutil

Tags: macos, hdiutil

I'm trying to script the creation of a hyrbid (iso/joliet/hfs) iso with hdiutil.  I can, for example, build an iso that hides things on the mac side like so:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -o foo.iso -hfs -joliet -iso -hide-hfs "{foo/bar.txt,foo/other.rtf}" foo
```

That's just an example of course, but the point is I can get it to hide say seven or eight example files I specify like that, with spaces in the filenames and verious dots and underscores.

But for my actual real-deal script I need to list in the neighborhood of 70 files, which does not seem to work when I test it.  The whole string is being passed in correctly, I know this because when you turn on '-verbose' it prints the string and says it doesn't match *anything*.

So my best guess is it has something to do with the length of the string passed in, but I don't see anything in the docs indicating that.  Any ideas?  Think it's a bug?  An alternative way of accomplishing this?

This is on Mac OS X 10.5.8, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Two [UPDATE, make it Three] (untested) suggestions:

1. use the `-plistin` option to
   specify all the parameters;
2. (better) try organizing the files to be
   hidden into directories, if
   necessary, so you can easily hide
   them by directory-specific globs
   rather than having to spell out each
   file.
3. [UPDATE] you could try using `mkisofs` from [cdrtools](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/) to make the ISO image.  `MacPorts` has a supported [port](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=cdrtools) of it.  It could be that the code in `hdiutil` was originally based on an earlier version.  In any case, you have the advantage of access to the source code and perhaps figuring out what the limitations are.

   P.S. There seems to be a couple of minor nits with the MacPorts port.  In particular, the
   `man` pages are installed in the wrong directory. [UPDATE: fixed in 3.00_1]

Comment: Number 1 is a good idea, but unfortunately did not work.  Number 2 is really not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: re: number 3, tried that out, but this program is shockingly bad at consuming command line arguments or providing feedback when it doesn't like something.  I may keep fiddling with it, but for now I think we're going to open a support incident with Apple inregards to hdituil, since that at least seemed to work well save for this one issue.  Hopefully that resolves it, otherwise I'll be stuck with mkisofs or even worse seeing if we can use hack solution like apple script with toast.  Thanks though.